# instantiate class in via nashorn

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

im thinking about replacing all my xml files and builders that i use for configuration with javascript / nashorn. lets say i have a java class that is builder style configuration object

```
class Configuration {
    String name;
    Configuration withName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
    int number;
    Configuration withNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
        return this;
    }
}
```

i would like to instantiate this class directly in javascript and have nashorn return to me an instance of it. i would like to code it in javascript like

```
{
    name: 'qwerty',
    number: 42
};
```

and then finally read the file, pass it into the script engine, and have it evaluate the object as an instance of Configuration.

- is this possible with a json like syntax?
- i wouldnt have a problem using the Packages.Configuration / Java.type("Configuration"); Java.extend(), but have yet to have any success with that.
- or would i have to make / use a proper reader for the returned value?

Comment: May be you start understanding Nashorn first and why don't you check this tutorial
http://java-latte.blogspot.in/2014/05/Oracle-Nashorn-JavaScript-Engine-Java-8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Nashorn won't support this from what I've seen from available docs and [JSR-223](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr223/index.html). You might need to use i.e. Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to deserialize JSON. And this should not be a problem, because Nashorn allows you to do almost anything in JavaScript: [A JavaFX Script Application Examples](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/fxamples.html).

You might also want to consider Groovy which has it's own map syntax which can be used inside constructors: [Groovy Goodness: Using Lists and Maps As Constructors](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-lists-and-maps-as.html). Groovy is often used to define configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could cheat a little by attaching a converter function to your configuration type.  This could be added easily on the JS side rather than trying to make it in Java.

```
var ConfigClass = Java.type('Configuration');

ConfigClass.fromJsObj = function(jsObj) {
    var newConfig = new ConfigClass();
    foreach(var prop in jsObj) {
        newConfig[prop] = jsObj[prop];
    }
    return newConfig;
}

var myConfig = ConfigClass.fromJsObj( { name: "qwerty", number: 42 } );
```